# DJANGO: error importing module

Tags: django

I've a project, with multiple apps.

In a view, I can do:

```
from app1.models import Foo
```

but I can't do:

```
from app2.buz import Buz
```

I've to do:

```
from myproject.app2.buz import Buz
```

to make it work.

why?

Maybe has some to do with that the module I'm trying to import is named like this?

from `charts.charts` import Chart

or it doesn't care what name is while the path is correct?

Answer (score 0):

django doesn't invoke any special magic around imports. Import behavior is identical to stock python behavior. Have you done something clever in your DJANGO_SETTINGS_ MODULE? Are your apps in the same directory? What does the following tell you?

```
from app1.models import Foo
Foo

from myproject.app2.buz import Buz
Buz
```

Comment: the two apps directories are inside the project directory.

and this olny happens with one concrete app, others works ok. I think I didn't do anything in django_settings...

Also, the view where I wish to import the two classes, is in a third app, in the project directory too.

Comment: At the interactive python prompt, when you type the module name after importing it... what does that tell you?

Comment: with an normal interactive python prompt, I get errors with two import ways, but I think it's related to the path and the fact that I'm using virtualenv.
from inside my IDE (pycharm), I run an interactive console and I get:
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.
but if I run a "django console":
from charts.charts import Chart
I get <<class charts.charts.Chart>> ,it didn't complain.